# Entity Relationship Model Databases

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship

I am practising some E-R model questions and came across this.

Construct   an  E-R model   for an  art gallery.    A   number  of  artists may exhibit their   paintings   at  the gallery.    Each    artist  has 
a   unique  id, name    (first  name    and last    name)   and an  address (street,    town    and postcode).  Each    painting    has a   unique
id,  a title,    date    completed   and     price   associated  with    it.     The     gallery     also    has     a   number  of  customers   who     have purchased paintings   from    the gallery.    Each    customer    has a   name,   address and phone   number(s).

I have so far constructed an artist entity with its attributes (ID as primary, composite name, composite address) and painting(ID as primary, date of completion as dervied, and rest as it is). But I need some help with the relationship advisor between the two and the gallery parts. Just a textual decsription will suffice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood the task, there's only one gallery, so you don't need to make any relationship to the gallery.

You just need two other tables:

- a customer table with their contact data and ID
- a sales table with the ID of the customer and the ID of the painting

Comment: but what the relationship advisor between all of them? That has to be linked through a gallery,no?

Comment: no, because there's just one gallery, you don't need an explicitly reference it

Answer (score -1):

[image]

If I'm correct, this is what you are looking for, correct?

Comment: ye, i'm sorry, im new to stackoverflow hehe, i normaly browse trough it, but i'm gonna start helping here and there when i can.
Thanks for editing my post Nisse. :)